# Include header html file in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have header.htm and footer.htm files and I would like to add these two files into my reactjs app. I tried to create header.htm as a component and render it in my app.js but it display as a string on the top not a page. ie. http://mydomain/include/header.htm.  How do I solve this problem?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
createMarkup()
{ 
 return { __html: "https://mydomain/include/header.htm"};
}
render(){
  return (

    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} ></div>
  );
}
}
export default Header;
```

app.js
     class App extends Component {

```
  render(){
    return (
       <Header />
    )
  }
 }
```

Comment: why not simply make proper components out of the markup?

Comment: Uh I am new to react. The header.htm file includes banner, dropdown menus, etc. It will be a lot of components then.

Comment: I think you are going to have a lot of trouble trying to insert all of the header content into a react component, why not put it in the index.html file that your react app lives in?

Comment: Well, if you want to learn React then do it the correct React way... otherwise - nothing wrong with vanilla JS...

Comment: I did add the header.htm in index.html but it does not show.    <!--#include virtual="https://mydomain/include/header.htm" -->  . Is that right way to do it?

Comment: @user788448 This totally depends on your server config. The thing you listed is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes . If the server wasn't configured to process html files with SSI then this won't work.

Comment: I tried this <script src="./MyHeader.js"></script> in index.html and created MyHeader.js as document.write("https://mydomain/include/header.htm"); but it still does not work.

Comment: It won't work like that. Decide if you want to address this from server or client side. For server side, use server side template. That's how things like this one are often done and this is specific to your config. . For client side, stick to React and put header contents to a component. Also, use `@` if you want users to receive notifications.

Comment: Okay, I  insert all the header content in the index.html files.